# Dojo ajax call parameter not passing for large data

Tags: javascript, ajax, dojo, jsp-tags

I am using dojo xhr post(ajax call) method for sending data from UI to server. I am passing data in content parameter as name value pair like following,

```
dojo.xhrPost({
        url : "actionName.action",
        handleAs : "json",
        content : {
            "selectedEntityJson" : JSON.stringify(selectedEntityJson),
            "templateTreeJson" : templateTreeJson
        },
        load : function(response) {

        }
    });
```

here, "templateTreeJson" is going to server only if the size of content is mininum. If large data is passed in "templateTreeJson", the data is not getting passed. It is not showing in firebug also. Is there any limitations in dojo ajax call? How can I pass the large data?

Comment: Could you tell me what you define as "large data"?

Comment: I tested with a string of 1.5 million characters and it still got posted: http://jsfiddle.net/dxch6urs/

Comment: A string of length 32773.

Comment: Is the request POSTed to the server, but with an empty "selectedEntityJson"?

Comment: Request is posted to Server with "selectedEntityJson" parameter alone. Only 
"selectedEntityJson" is sent, "templateTreeJson" is not sent. In firebug i can see that,

selectedEntityJson {"a":"1","b":"2","c":"3"}  

If i put console.log for "templateTreeJson" before ajax call it is displaying correctly. while sending to server it is not posted. A small length of data in  "templateTreeJson" is sent.

Comment: Please try to reproduce this behavior on a JSFiddle. You can extend mine (posted in comment) and fork it if necessary. There must be something else wrong, because it can clearly support more than 3000 characters. Provide the contents of the strings you are trying to post.